# audio interruption notification not being fired on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

My team is developing an iOS App that uses the microphone 24/7 to detect known TV/Radio programmes by their sound.  The App has the right permissions etc to continue to run in the background and we need to handle loss of audio session to another App, Siri, a Phone call etc etc  So we register to listen for the audio interruption NSNotification in order that we can gracefully shut down our processing when a call starts then resume it when it ends.

When we look at the logs while running the App from source in XCode we see expected behaviours for all devices, except an iPhone 6 Plus.

Specifically, for all devices we have tested (iPhone 5, iPhone 6) we see the interruption due to a Phone Call START but for Phone Call END the audio interruption does not get fired at all on iPhone 6 Plus.
So for example, when I plug in my iPhone 5C and look at the logs I get an interruption on Phone Call start then another one when I end the call... but when I try the EXACT same code on iPhone 6 Plus, I get the audio interruption notification on call start but nothing when I end the call.  iOS 10.2 on all devices tested - it simply looks like on iPhone 6 Plus the audio interruption mechanism does not function correctly for iPhone 6 Plus...

Looks like an iOS bug so I have logged it with Apple.  Anyone have any ideas what might be up or experienced something similar?
Thanks!